# Heigh 100% independent of the page content

Tags: css

I have some layout like follow exemple bellow:

```
<div id="maim"  style="background-color: white;">
    <div id="menu" style="background-color: green;">
        <!-- menu 280px in the left side -->
    </div>
    <div id="header" style="background-color: blue;">
        <!-- header 100% -->
    </div>
    <div id="content" style="background-color: grey;">
        <!-- div where the content will be implemented -->
    </div>
</div>
```

In my css style I need that the menu always appear in 100% heigh independent of the height of the content div. In this moment when my content is greater than the visible area of the my browser, when I scrool my page the menu end in the first view area of the browser.

Have something that can I do to solve this problem?

My CSS is bellow:

```
#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 280px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #182C38;
  color: #7f8a94;
  float: left;
  z-index: 2;
}

#header {
  padding-left: 305px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 105px;
  background-color: #2888c1;
  color: #7f8a94;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#content {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 280px;
  margin-top: 105px;
  padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 280px);
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 280px);
  width: -o-calc(100% - 280px);
  width: calc(100% - 280px);
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try position fixed for menu:

```
#menu {
  position: fixed;
  width: 280px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #182C38;
  color: #7f8a94;
  float: left;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Or set 100vh instead of 100%:

```
#menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 280px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #182C38;
  color: #7f8a94;
  float: left;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the fixed position solve the problem in some better way for me.

The 100vh not work for me. Thank your again.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you seem to have a typo in the ID of your top-most div (it says #maim rather than #main). Assuming this is not the issue, you apply a 100% height on your content div. Since that one is stacked below the header, it will result in 100% of the viewport + the height of your header. Try subtracting the header height (inc. padding, unless you use box-sizing: border-box) from your content height, e.g. height: calc(100% - 130px);

Alternatively, you could go for another (simpler) approach not even using any absolute positioning:

```
<div id="main"  style="background-color: white;">
    <div id="menu" style="background-color: green;">
        <!-- menu 280px in the left side -->
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="header" style="background-color: blue;">
        header
      </div>
      <div id="content" style="background-color: grey;">
        content
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

body, html {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#main {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#menu {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 280px;
  background-color: green;
}

#wrapper {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 280px);
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

#header {
  height: 105px;
  display: table-row;
}

#content {
  display: table-row;
}
```

If you don't want to use table layouts, remove those properties and apply height: calc(100% - 105px) to #content.

Answer (score 1):

Replace your CSS code:

Here is working demo: https://output.jsbin.com/zopasa

```
body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#menu {
  position: absolute;
  width: 280px;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #182C38;
  color: #7f8a94;
  float: left;
  z-index: 2;
}

#header {
  padding-left: 305px;
  padding-top: 25px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 105px;
  background-color: #2888c1;
  color: #7f8a94;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

#content {
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 280px;
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 280px);
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 280px);
  width: -o-calc(100% - 280px);
  width: calc(100% - 280px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best easiest and trustable approach for you issues is using view port units.

```
 . target {
   width: 100vw; /* makes the target full width of the viewport size. */
   height: 100vh; /* makes full height */
 }
```

The browser support is solid except IE.

Note:-
Found typo in your html code id="main"